# Missing modules while running npm install --only=dev and future fix

Tags: npm, npm-install

I had three error messages for different modules while running:

```
npm install --only=dev.
```

I installed them manually by running:

```
npm install mkdirp
npm install request 
npm install npmlog
```

How can I avoid this on other (next) dev machines?

Can I just add these three to the beginning of the "devDependencies" list in package.json?

Comment: devDependencies (npm install --save-dev PACKAGE) = dependencies required during the development cycle (stuff like prettier, eslint, lint-staged, husky, babel, typescript) // dependencies (npm install PACKAGE) = dependencies needed during runtime (npmlog, request)

Comment: @LoganDevine Not clear what you mean. So -save-dev adds them to the package.json?

Comment: Adds them to devDependencies. Use npm install for dependencies and npm install --save-dev for utilities

Answer (score 1):

`--only=dev` will only install devDependencies. If you need these dependencies, either run `npm install` without the `--only` flag or add them you your `devDependencies`.

Comment: When I run npm install (even now, after manually installing them) I get errors, that's why I tried to do it manually with --only-dev

Comment: @sanchez we can't help you if you don't share the errors